# Symfony Docker PHPunit Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: docker, symfony, phpunit

I have a problem when i try to execute php bin/phpunit from docker.

Warning: require(/user/project/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-7.5-0/vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /user/project/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-7.5-0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69

If i execute php bin/phpunit from terminal in my computer it works.
If i delete phpunit folder from /bin directory in symfony project and i try to execute php bin/phpunit from docker it works (after phpunit re-installation in /bin folder) on docker machine but not on my pc. Perhaps the problem is in symlink but i'm not able to solve this issue.

Comment: the error message looks extremely weird, specifically the paths in it. what exactly are you linking and using? why does your `bin` folder in the project has a `.phpunit` subfolder? not to be judgemental but you're project setup might be very non-conventional creating all your problems ...

Comment: .phpunit folder in /bin is created when i execute php bin/phpunit. After this command i get this : No composer.json found in the current directory, showing available packages from packagist.org
Creating a "phpunit/phpunit" project at "./phpunit-7.5-0"
Installing phpunit/phpunit (7.5.20)
..... But composer.json exists in folder

Comment: have you tried adding phpunit to your composer.json (as dev dependency) and running vendor/bin/phpunit instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that when you build your container you execute the `composer install` command.
If the problem still persist please share a snap of your Dockerfile

Comment: symfony 5.0 automatically create /bin/.phpunit folder after command ./bin/phpunit to execute test. I don't know why first execution of ./bin/phpunit generate a "No composer.json found in the current directory, showing available packages from packagist.org" and install all dependencies.

Comment: The bin/phpunit is a symlink to the one in the Vendor folder. Please check that. And again please execute composer install again so that it is recreated. I had this exact problem 3 weeks ago.